# Array.push is not working for local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am creating a shopping cart where user can add an item to cart. Once user clicked the addtocart button, I want to save the product id, name, price and quantity to local storage and then retrieve them on the cart page. So I tried this

```
  var cart = new Array;

    if (cart != []) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage["cart"]);
    }

  $('#addtocart').on('click', function(e) {

var qty = document.getElementById("p-qty").value;
var li = $(this).parent();


var product = {};
product.id = productid;
product.name = document.getElementById("nomenclature").innerHTML;
product.price = document.getElementById("productprice").innerHTML;
product.quantity = qty;

addToCart(product);
});


 function addToCart(product) {
// Retrieve the cart object from local storage
if (localStorage) {
    var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage['cart']);            

    cart.push(product);

    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

// window.location = "html/cart.html"   
}
```

but I keep getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: cart.push is not a function

What am I doing wrongly and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is `cart` an object or an array?

Comment: @OmarEinea i want it to be an array so that i can push other arrays to it

Comment: *i want it to be an array*, what you want and what it actually is are two different things. Let's start with what it is and then see if we can help you make it what you want. So what is the type of `cart` now? If you're not sure, just paste the content of `localStorage['cart']` in your question and we'll figure it out for you. Just do `console.log(localStorage['cart'])`, then copy and paste it in the question.

Comment: So where do you first create the localstorage key with the array? Or are you assumingit would know it is an array?

Comment: @chris but he used `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, didn't he? I'm sorry, I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't check that localStorage['cart'] is defined and don't check that the deserialized variable is an array. I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
function addToCart(product) {
    if (localStorage) {
        var cart;
        if (!localStorage['cart']) cart = [];
        else cart = JSON.parse(localStorage['cart']);            
        if (!(cart instanceof Array)) cart = [];
        cart.push(product);

        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    } 
}
```

Note, however, that if you have a serialized object or other non-array variable in `localStorage['cart']`, it will be overwritten with this method.

Answer (score 3):

**localStorage** in HTML5 is Object, you can set item by using **.setItem()** and get item by **.getItem()**

Demo get old values, push new value and save values with localStorage

```
    var Values = [];

    //get olds values
    Values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Storage')); 

    //push new value
    Values.push(item);

    //saved values
    localStorage.setItem('Storage', JSON.stringify(Values));
```

Comment: This is not an answer/solution to the question/problem. It's just another way of doing things. I have no idea why it is upvoted. You can also do `localStorage.Storage = "test";` and `var test = localStorage.Storage;`. I find that nicer ;).

Comment: And your answer would have the same exact problem as the OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

Now with your edit, problem you have here is this makes no sense. First You set the array to be empty, so it will always be empty. Now second issue is `[]` will never equal `new Array` so it will always go into the if statement. And since you probably never set `localStorage["cart"]` with anything, it will be invalid.

```
var cart = new Array;  // <-- you define an array?
if (cart != []) {  // <- than you check the array you just created? How would it have a value if this check would actually work?
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage["cart"]);
}
```

So what you need to do is get rid of that if, since it does nothing. Next you just need to check localstorage if it has a value, if it does not, than set it to an emoty array. So add a conditional that if it is undefined, it uses a new array

Now what your codde should have been was

```
var cart = []; //define the array
if (localStorage["cart"]) {  // Check that it has a value in storage
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage["cart"]); //If yes, parse it
}
```

or another way could be

```
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage['cart'] || '[]');
```

Comment: And I updated my answer which was correct off the guess.... Your logic was switched.